# Unnessary paste issues in the start while using bash shell

Tags: bash, terminal, clipboard

So I am using the bash shell with st terminal emulator (issues occur with different terminal emulator also), what happens is if I paste a string of text in my shell, I got a issue like this
[image]

But if I use any other shell like zsh it doesn't have this issue, it paste just fine. It actually doesn't affect the actual command but it is kind of annoying while editing the command. I have tried other terminal emulator also, & the issue still exist, here is a gif while pasting the command

[image]

Specs which might help:

```
OS: Arch Linux 
Shell: bash 5.1.8 
WM: dwm 
Terminal: st 
Terminal Font: Inconsolata
```

My `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
# PS1
_GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
_RESET=$(tput sgr0)
export PS1="${_GREEN}\W \$ ${_RESET}"

# Exports
export PATH=$PATH:/home/anant/.local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/npm
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
export MANPAGER="nvim -c 'set ft=man' -"
export EDITOR="nvim"
export BROWSER="firefox"

# Aliases
alias ls='exa -la'
alias la='exa -a'
alias ll='exa -l'
alias update="yay -Syyu --devel --noconfirm"
alias install="yay -S --noconfirm"
alias remove="yay -Rs --noconfirm"
alias config="/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME"
alias configurl="config remote set-url origin"
alias giturl="git remote set-url origin"
alias v="nvim"
alias music="cd ~/Music;youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg" 
alias sx="sx sh ~/.xinitrc"
alias cat="bat"
alias less="bat"
alias fm6000="fm6000 -c blue -de dwm -n"
alias mpv="devour mpv"
alias zathura="devour zathura"
alias sxiv="devour sxiv"
alias lowriter="devour lowriter"

# Personal Aliases
alias code="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/"
alias pythonProject="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/pythonProject/"
alias webProjects="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/webDevProject"
alias learncss="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/learnCSS/"

# fzf
source /usr/share/fzf/completion.bash
source /usr/share/fzf/key-bindings.bash
```

Comment: Your time would be better spent figuring out how to *describe* your problem and actually ask a question.  It certainly wouldn't be completely wasted time like, for instance, making an animated gif.    Also: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: I will guess you are using CTRL+C to copy. The problem is that CTRL+C in most terminals is _not_ "copy", but "Interrupt! Break! Stop! Abort! Cancel that last command I typed before it wipes out my hard drive!". Many terminal programs will handle CTRL+SHIFT+C and CTRL+SHIFT+P as "copy" and "paste", respectively.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the issue is and I don't quite see what the animation is trying to show.

Comment: @C.M. No I only have in pasting issues not copying. I also know that ctrl+c is for breaking/interrupting

Comment: @cas Ok, thanks for suggestion, but I don't have any idea how can I explain you what the error is coming

Comment: @AnantGupta: then please edit your question to: (1) remove or transcribe the image (not everyone here can easily view or follow images or animations), and (2) clarify what you are asking, what the problem is, and/or what you have searched/tried/failed/etc. The only issue I saw in what you have is the tell-tale ^C marker indicating a CTRL+C interrupt was sent. The only other "issue" I see might be that you are asking why certain parts get _highlighted_ erratically, and that would typically be the result of many factors, including terminal emulatoin and prompt display handling.

Comment: In [a comment](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unix/img/site-background-image.svg?v=adf85a88e194) you mention an error.  What is the error?

Comment: So, is your problem: _"If I paste text into my terminal emulator, the text stays highlighted even if I start to mark new/different text for editing in the very same terminal window I just pasted into, applying a XOR-like logic if the regions overlap?"_

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was happening because of my **PS1 prompt**. I was just messing up with my PS1 prompt, removed the custom PS1 prompt lines & I was done. There were no issue then, now this is my bashrc

```
# Exports
export PATH=$PATH:/home/anant/.local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/npm
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
export MANPAGER="nvim -c 'set ft=man' -"
export EDITOR="nvim"
export BROWSER="firefox"

# Aliases
alias ls='exa -la'
alias la='exa -a'
alias ll='exa -l'
alias update="yay -Syyu --devel --noconfirm"
alias install="yay -S --noconfirm"
alias remove="yay -Rs --noconfirm"
alias config="/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME"
alias configurl="config remote set-url origin"
alias giturl="git remote set-url origin"
alias v="nvim"
alias music="cd ~/Music;youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 --prefer-ffmpeg" 
alias sx="sx sh ~/.xinitrc"
alias cat="bat"
alias less="bat"
alias fm6000="fm6000 -c blue -de dwm -n"
alias mpv="devour mpv"
alias zathura="devour zathura"
alias sxiv="devour sxiv"
alias lowriter="devour lowriter"

# Personal Aliases
alias code="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/"
alias pythonProject="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/pythonProject/"
alias webProjects="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/webDevProject"
alias learncss="cd ~/git-dir/personal/codingPlayground/learnCSS/"

# fzf
source /usr/share/fzf/completion.bash
source /usr/share/fzf/key-bindings.bash
```